# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow on item creation or change starts after 5 minutes

Tags: 2013, workflow, timer-jobs, whencreated

Why Workflow start needs 5 minutes?
Have not experienced it earlier.
Is it normal? you can see on below images.
How can i avoid this slowness without changing some SP timer job settings? Is there any way?

**before 5 minute**

[image: 1]

**after 5 minute passed**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than 1 year I found an answer.

This happens when you have WF-s automatically cascading each other.

For example, if we have two lists, named A and B and if WF in the list A automatically gets executed to create new item in the list B, and you have another WF in list B to execute automatically when new item is created, than system (SP) delays execution of chained WF to avoid possible infinite loop (holds execution for 5 minutes).

In other words this is happening only cause of the defensive purposes from SP side, to not implement something bad, accidentally or intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have many workflows in your environment, so they're getting queued. Please check this for more details:

http://softlanding.ca/blog/tuning-sharepoint-workflow-engine

Comment: Actually i have no more than 5 WF-s on that particular site

Comment: I am using [Harepoint Workflow Scheduler](https://www.harepoint.com/products/harepointworkflowscheduler/Default.aspx) for one Workflow, which runs in every 2 minutes. May it have some impact?

Comment: It could be, I know that SP workflows timejob would run every 5 minutes. but you would have to disable the one running in your environment each 2 minutes to verify. Also you would need to check other site collections for workflows queued, as this is a global thing, not just on the site level